# Two Column Table View ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to implement a two column list of options. How it would work is that the user selects two elements: one on the left and one on the right. At that point the selected options will be highlighted. At the bottom would be a "select" button.

How would I go about implementing this. Would I use UITableView?

Comment: i'd have to say you would use 2 separate UITableView(s) in one ViewController. You just set the width of one to half the screen, and set the width of the other to the remaining size of the screen and that should give you the functionality you're aiming for

Comment: I have gone through the same and yes you have to create two separate table views. i agree with @user2277872

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a [two-column UIPickerView](https://www.google.com/search?q=two%20column%20uipickerview&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49641647,d.eWU,pv.xjs.s.en_US.NyLNrjc7wJY.O&biw=1438&bih=692&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&authuser=0) to accomplish this. It is a native iOS control that will provide the functionality you are looking for in a way that users will understand.

Comment: +1 this is a good option when the text for each option is not exceeding few letters.

Comment: +1 Good suggestion, but consider rephrasing it so that it's an answer instead of a question.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with single `UITableView` as well,

Create a custom cell with two `UILabel`'s with half width of the cell width. For e.g. If the cell width would be 320 then you've to add two `UILabel` with 160 of width, or the width you want.

You can name labels like, `UILabel *lblFirstCol`, `*lblSecondCol;` for easy differenctiation.

This will help you in,

1. If you'll have no data for any of the columns then you can hide that particular label.
2. You don't need to use two `UITableViews`.
3. You can scroll in single table easily then then the two tables.
4. Can be more customizable UI then to use `UIPickerView` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can shoehorn this into one table view by inserting multiple tableviews.

Other UI flow you could consider is to let the user select 'first option' then use a 'continue' button and then select the 'second' option and click on next/done button action.similar to how a brand new iPhone walks you through the setup.

This way, you can just use a single table view controller for selecting one option at a time - giving your users neat and simple navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to *user2277872*,

- First you need create a parent viewController that has two container view.
- Then create two  child view controller that contains table view each.
- Add the child controller to parent so can  manager them in parent.
- The "select" button added in parent view controller.